# How to upload a certificate to Amazon ELB?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl, amazon-elb

I've generated the pem files for a new certificate which we recently purchased from comodo, using this link as a guide: "https://guillaumemaka.com/2015/05/06/install-your-comodo-certificates-to-amazon-aws.html".

However, I'm unclear as to how to actually replace the current cert on the Amazon ELB. When I click on "Upload a new SSL certificate to AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)", it asks me to enter the file names instead of selecting them. Do I enter the local path, or am I prompted for that later, or not at all?

Comment: See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-add-or-delete-listeners.html#add-listener-console

Comment: Ah, I see. On re-reading I realized it wants the contents pasted. I will give it a try.

Comment: You should copy and past the certificate and the key into the corresponding fields on the form - http://i.imgur.com/v9EKgtW.png

Comment: Here's a [very similar StackOverflow post/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468996/installing-ssl-cert-on-amazon-ec2-elb/35518839#35518839) on the same topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) to achieve this task.

After the certificate is uploaded there, you will see it under the SSL certificate ID in the environment configuration.